# Activate script tags from turbo frames - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

When we return turbo frames in post request sometimes it is esential run javascript for example if I am calling a resource to update, there are two possible cases

1. when it saves sucessfully then close the modal
2. When it is not saved then show validation messages in modal

In both cases I am sending frame (its intentional not to use redirect or render).

Recently I found this issue & PR in github which is now merged.
https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/192

But it is not documented yet how to use it actually, Need help on that

Comment: If you use Stimulus, any controller in your turbo frame response will get activated automatically. Stimulus and Turbo are meant to work together like that.